# TravisCI deploy cannot find setup.py

Tags: python, github, travis-ci, pypi

It seems like it should be fairly easy to set up automatic releases of my python project (on GitHub) to PyPi: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pypi/

So, I added the following to my `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: DanHickstein
  on:
    tags: true
  password:
    secure: GHhpt4Ssv2VQh6...
```

It almost works, but I get the following error of TravisCI:

```
Preparing deploy
Authenticated as DanHickstein

Deploying application
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ValueError: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/*'
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I cannot fathom why `setup.py` cannot be found. It is right there in the same directory as `.travis.yml`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [following line](https://github.com/PyAbel/PyAbel/blob/v0.7.3b/.travis.yml#L26) in the `install` stage:

```
- cd ~/
```

Make sure you are back in the root of your projects directory before deploying, maybe in the `before_deploy` stage.

Comment: Yes, I think that this was the issue - thanks for your help! I suppose when I can't find a file, I should make sure that I am looking in the correct directory! Whoopsie.